# What does Ivy mean in this exchange?

Tags: dialogue, poison-ivy

Early in the 1992 movie Poison Ivy, Ivy (Drew Barrymore's character) has the following exchange with Darryl Cooper (Tom Skerritt):

> Darryl: Where do you live?
>
> Ivy: My aunt gets money for letting me stay there.
>
> Darryl: I get the picture.

What is the picture that Darryl gets? Why is Ivy's aunt paid to let her stay with her?

Comment: My initial suspicion is that 1) she doesn't want him to know where she lives exactly, and 2) her aunt is willing to *overlook* her line of work for a fee. Although it's been many years since I've seen it.

Comment: Darryl is a wealthy TV executive who pays for his daughter to attend a prep school. Ivy is from the "other side of the tracks", whose aunt receives a welfare check because she is fostering her niece. Ivy attends the same school, we assume through a scholarship of some kind.

Comment: Help a newbie out here. @CGCampbell's comment is a perfectly legitimate answer. Why is it not an Answer? Even in the comments box, it says "Avoid answering questions in the comments," and yet I see more answers in comments than in the answers. Is it to avoid downvotes?

Comment: If I recall correctly, I did this at work and did not have time to source it properly. Then, I forgot about it. Even if I did remember, I'd have probably left it a comment. I don't need the up votes, and a few (or many actually) down votes won't hurt me. I'd have left it for someone who could use the up vote boost to gain abilities, such as comments.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Darryl is a wealthy TV executive who pays for his daughter to attend a prep school. Ivy is from the "other side of the tracks", whose aunt receives a welfare check because she is fostering her niece. Ivy attends the same school, we assume through a scholarship of some kind.